# Error using D3 with typescript in Visual Studio Code

Tags: d3.js, typescript

I am pretty new to typescript. I am using Visual Studio Code as my editor and using gulp to execute typescript. I am looking to use d3 in my typescript code. I installed d3 using the below,

```
npm install d3
typings install d3 --save
```

Below is my package.json

```
  {
 "name": "proj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.3",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "registry:npm/d3#3.0.0+20160723033700"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "files": [
        "src/main.ts",
        "src/greet.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

When I import d3 in my TS code now as shown below,

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

it gives me the following error

[ts] Could not find a declaration file for module 'd3'. 'c:/.../VS/proj/node_modules/d3/build/d3.node.js' implicitly has an 'any' type

Can anyone pls let me know what am I doing incorrectly

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

even i was facing the same issue,
but then i tried calling it in `index.html` file like,

```
`<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`
```

then, declare d3 in your .ts file like below,

```
declare var d3: any;
```

hope this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Install this dependency:

```sh
npm i --save-dev @types/d3
```

If you are using VS Code as an editor, after installing that dependency, reload the window to have the error disappear from VS Code too.